# C++ WriteToProcessMemory() Unexpected Results

Tags: c++, windows, assembly

## About the Situation

I'm simply trying to inject an opcode (NOP) into a game's process to simply allow me to have unlimited ammo (that is, not do anything to deduct ammo when I shoot). I'm no expert in C++, but I'm not a *complete* novice either. With this being said, I'm puzzled as to why this code is crashing the game upon writing to its memory:

## Code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

void DisplayMenu();

HWND hwnd = FindWindow(0, TEXT("Zombie Shooter 2"));
HANDLE handle;
DWORD pid;

char NOPAmmo[] = "\x90";

int main() {
    hwnd = FindWindow(0, TEXT("Zombie Shooter 2"));
    GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, &pid);
    handle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, pid);

    if (!WriteProcessMemory(handle, (void*)0x4Af3BE, &NOPAmmo, sizeof(NOPAmmo),
                            NULL)) {
        printf("Failed to write to memory!");
    } else {
        printf("Success!");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I initially tried setting the variable "NOPAmmo" to be like this:

```
BYTE NOPAmmo = 200;
```

The code wouldn't crash the game, but it didn't have any effect either. Here's a screenshot of the instruction I'm overwriting (in case that it helps, I'm using OllyDbg):

[image]

Comment: You tagged this as C++. You wrote C++ in the title. You gave C++ code. Why did you add the C tag?

Comment: It's simply a mix of the two. I'll remove it.

Comment: Since you are trying to overwrite a multi-byte instruction, you should use multiple nops or an appropriate multi-byte nop or a jump. If you only overwrite the first byte, the cpu will try to interpret the remaining bytes as an instruction and probably crash.

Comment: It seems you have changed the address that your program modifies, but not updated the disassembly...

Comment: So would it be something like: NOPAmmo[] = "\x90\x90\x90\x90"?

Comment: @j_random_hacker Yes, I'm sorry about that, I'll try to fix that

Comment: The instruction is clearly 3 bytes long, so it would be *exactly* like `char NOPAmmo[] = "\x90\x90\x90";`.

Comment: @j_random_hacker I'm still having no outcome. I can shoot a few bullets off before the game crashes (it's also not NOP'ing the instruction it seems.

Comment: Remember that memory addresses inside a process are relative to the process's base address.  `OpenProcess()` gives you the base address, then you can add an offset to that to get the desired target memory address.  Don't hard code the final address directly, in case the process is not loaded at the expected base address.

Comment: Also, make sure you aren't running into issues with null-terminated strings - i.e. `"\x90\x90\x90"` is 4 bytes - the first three are NOP instructions, the fourth is the start of an `add` instruction

Comment: And don't forget that after editing an instruction code in a currently running process you should flush the instruction cache to ensure the modified version will be executed - [FlushInstructionCache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679350%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

The instruction you're trying to NOP is 3 bytes:
`01 43 40`

You're only writing 1 NOP and therefore the `43 40` are still executing.  To solve this problem you need to NOP all 3, by changing your byte array to:

`"\x90\x90\x90"`

and then using 3 as the fourth argument to WriteProcessMemory(), which is the size of data you're ovewriting.

Comment: Or better a 3-byte NOP like `66 66 90` instead of 3 separate NOP instructions.